# problem with Install APK Programmatically in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have scenario where I have to download apk in background and install it without prompting any dialog to user. However when I try to install it using below code File

```
string mypath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;

            var filePath = Path.Combine(mypath, fileName);
          
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    string extention = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(filePath)).ToString());
                    string mimeType = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extention);
                    Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
                    Android.Net.Uri fileUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.PackageName + ".provider", new Java.IO.File(filePath));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                    intent.SetDataAndType(fileUri, mimeType);


                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                    context.StartActivity(intent);
                }
```

and below code for xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_file" path="." />
</paths>
```

and below code for AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.fileprovider">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:label="Fileprovider.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
    <provider
     android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
     android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
     android:exported="false"
     android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

but when click button to open .apk file view below error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwN6I.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install APK without the prompt on Android. Actually I don't think you can do the similar thing on any modern operating system.

Comment: how to implement Auto update app without use of appStore in android?

Comment: @AliRajiry I wasn't aware that you are looking for no app store solution. Then it is likely possible, there are alternative apps stores and they install new apps after you install their app. However I am not sure how they do it and I think that there aren't too many people knowing that, but you can always ask. You should edit the question to stress that this is for solution without any app store.